# undefined reference to <...> (&...)

Tags: c++, rest, parameters, pack

Hi I'm studying parameters packs. I have just written a sample code and I have got a couple of bugs.

Code:

```
 #include <string>

  using namespace std;

 template<typename T> void inputer(){}

 template<typename T,typename... Rest> void inputer(const T& x, Rest... rest)
{
cin>>x;
inputer<T>(rest...);
}

int main()
{
int a,b;
inputer<int>(a,b);
return 0;
}
```

I don't see any errors (I'm not experienced with parameter packs).
How to get an effect like I'm trying to.

Regards

PS: When I change

```
template <typename T> void inputer(){}
```

to

```
template <typename T> void inputer();
```

the code doesn't compile. Why ?

Comment: You haven't told us what effect you're trying to get, or what you *are* getting. How are we expected to help?

Comment: @Jonbi2 How do you expect `cin >> x;` to go with `const T& x` and `Rest` passed by value?

Comment: In addition to answer given: make empty `inputer` non-template, get rid of explicit template arguments and let deduction do its work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass all arguments by reference. Reference to non-const to be exact:

```
template <typename T, typename... Rest>
void inputer(T& x, Rest&...) { .. }
```

`cin >> x` can't modify `const int&` and if you pass `Rest` by value, the input won't reflect in passed `b`, but in a copy inside a parameter pack.

> Why does
>
> ```
> template <typename T> void inputer();
> ```
>
> not compile?

Because it has to be defined, why wouldn't it be? If it had a code inside, it would be executed after all arguments are printed.

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, the `inputer` for no arguments does not need to be a template, just an overload:

```
void inputer();
```

and recurse like this:

```
inputer(rest...);
```

`T` is wrong, it will only spoil the whole thing if the first parameter of the pack is different from the first.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

`void inputer(const T& x, Rest... rest)`: `x` is const and therefore not usable for `cin >> x`. Also `rest` should be passed as reference.
Change it to `void inputer(T& x, Rest... rest)`.

`inputer<T>(rest...);` must be `inputer<Rest&...>(rest...);`

You should check if `cin >> x` succeded or fails.

Your `inputer` always needs at least one template argument. Due to its recursive structure it might be called without any.
You should provide a solution for this case.

---

**Working version**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename...Args> bool inputer();

template<typename T, typename... Rest> 
bool inputer(T& x, Rest&... rest)
{
    if (!(cin >> x)) return false;
    return inputer<Rest...>(rest...);
}

template<typename T>
bool inputer(T& x)
{
    if (!(cin >> x)) return false;
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    inputer<int, int>(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```